# Get specific sheet range using gspread acell

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I want to get specific sheet range which consists of multiple row for example :

[image]

So my code is :

```
    work_book = sheet.get_worksheet(sheet_idx)
    row_value = work_book.acell('A1:C3').value
    print(row_value)
```

When I run the code I only get value from cell `A1` (which is empty). If I use `A2:C3`, the result will be `Hello`. I expected it will show entire sheet range. Should I loop or something? Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`acell` only returns a single cell. For a range you should use `get` https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.get

Comment: Totally missed that out. Thanks!